# JUnit5 - conditional using of extension

Tags: java, junit, junit5, junit5-extension-model

Is it possible to use extension depending on some condition in JUnit5?

I have extension that collect and send test run results to external service (TestRail). But I want to have it enabled for remote runs and disabled for local runs. E.g. something like this:

`TestRailListener implements BeforeAllCallback, TestWatcher`

```
@BeforeAll
public void beforeAll() {
    if(!Objects.equals(System.getProperty("runType"), "local")) {
        Extension e = new TestRailListener().enable();
    }
```

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: You could implement an extension that delegates to the one you want to enable conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

JUnit Jupiter provides [Programmatic Extension Registration](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-programmatic).

So you can configure you extensions with additional parameters at runtime.

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but (if I'm not missing something) via instance/static field extension IS already registered. And I need possibility to not register it at all.